# How to calculate the correct position for a matrix of circles to fit inside given view with proportional gaps?

Tags: ios, swift

I am pretty new to iOS development and I am trying to display a 10x10 grid inside a UIView respecting its bounds and I would like that the circles would be calculated based on the available width/height of the device.

What I tried so far without luck:

```
func setUpPoints() {
    let matrixSize = 10
    let diameter = (min(painelView.frame.size.width, painelView.frame.size.height) / CGFloat(matrixSize + 1)).rounded(.down)
    let radius = diameter / 2

    for i in 0...matrixSize {

        for j in 0...matrixSize {
            let x = CGFloat(i) * diameter + radius
            let y = CGFloat(j) * diameter + radius
            let frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: diameter, height: diameter)
            let circle = Circle(frame: frame)
            circle.tag = j * matrixSize + i + 1
            painelView.addSubview(circle)

        }
    }

}
```

My goal is to distribute the circles inside the gray rectangle proportionally so it will look like the Android pattern lock screen:

[image]

Can someone please give me some pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers here http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: FYI - you shouldn't completely change your question like you did. My answer was based on your original question. When you completely change the question, existing answers no longer seem to make sense. You should have updated your question to leave the original information plus some additions based on the changes you made.

Comment: It sounds better indeed. Next time I will be sure to keep the previous version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, then the following line:

```
let radius = (painelView.frame.size.width + painelView.frame.size.height) / CGFloat(matrixSize * 2)
```

should be:

```
let radius = (min(painelView.frame.size.width, painelView.frame.size.height) / CGFloat(matrixSize + 1)).rounded(.down)
```

The above change will allow the "square" of circles fit within whichever is smaller - the view's width or height, allowing for a gap around the "square" equal to half the diameter of each circle.

You also need to change both loops to start with 0.

```
for i in 0..<matrixSize {
    for j in 0..<matrixSize {
```

BTW - your `radius` variable is really the `diameter`. And `gap` is really the `radius`.

The following code provides a border around the square of circles and it includes some space between the circles. Adjust as needed.

```
func setUpPoints() {
    let matrixSize = 10
    let borderRatio = CGFloat(0.5) // half a circle diameter - change as desired
    let gapRatio = CGFloat(0.25) // quarter circle diameter - change as desired
    let squareSize = min(painelView.frame.size.width, painelView.frame.size.height)
    let diameter = (squareSize / (CGFloat(matrixSize) + 2 * borderRatio + CGFloat(matrixSize - 1) * gapRatio)).rounded(.down)
    let centerToCenter = (diameter + diameter * gapRatio).rounded(.down)
    let borderSize = (diameter * borderRatio).rounded()

    for i in 0..<matrixSize {
        for j in 0..<matrixSize {
            let x = CGFloat(i) * centerToCenter + borderSize
            let y = CGFloat(j) * centerToCenter + borderSize
            let frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: diameter, height: diameter)
            let circle = Circle(frame: frame)
            circle.tag = j * matrixSize + i + 1
            painelView.addSubview(circle)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the edited answer. I changed the layout for it to be easier and updated the code as you instructed. As you can see it is really better now but stil outside bounds. Also I need to have a gap between all the items so it will be easier to select them individually.

Comment: You didn't update the `for` loops like I showed. Look closely at the `for` loops in my answer. Also count the circles in your updated image.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry for that. Indeed it will fit nicely now. Is there a way to add a spacing between the items?

Comment: Sure, do you want a fixed sized gap (say 10pts) or do you want a proportional gap (say 1/4 the circle diameter or whatever)?

Comment: Proportional gap is better, because I think it will adjust better to a different device

Comment: That is perfect. Thanks a lot!